# Migrate created AWS EB and Route 53 resources to another IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am experimenting creating a web application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Route 53 (Hosted Zone). As I am quite new to AWS, it is only later that I learned that it is not a good idea to have them created using the root account. Now I am creating a user and group in IAM but I have no idea how to move these resources as owned by the user. (I am not sure if this is possible though)

Comment: EBS == Elastic Block Store, not Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These resources are not "owned" by a user.  They are owned by the account.

If you created the resources with the root user, that's fine.  You don't need to change anything about the resources -- you just need to stop using the root credentials in the future.

Other users, groups, roles with sufficient permissions can interact with these resources, no differently than if they had been originally created not using the root credentials.